# Send Direct Message with Photo

Tags: twitter

I am trying to send a direct message to a Twitter user, but with an image attached. I have already achieved this with the code 1. However to get the image ID I have to post a Tweet (Code 2), and I know the procedure is not, could someone help me with an example of the proper way to upload an image to Twitter without posting it as a Tweet, please.

**Code1**:

```
<?php
session_start();

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$consumer_key = 'Rh4UxxxxxxxxxxxIs7G';
$consumer_secret = 'fUw7mPjGkBnZKmxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbSHxynfkJGgz';
$oauth_token = '133xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx22593-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxGhpcVmrrlgNN23';
$oauth_token_secret = 'b6xyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxgPh3QdSEBxKj1fdc';
$userId = '13367xxxxxx68';

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
$content = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
$data = [
    'event' => [
        'type' => 'message_create',
        'message_create' => [
            'target' => [
                'recipient_id' => $userId
            ],
            'message_data' => [
               'attachment' => [
                        'type' => 'media',
                        'media' => [
                                    'id' => '1365060529463697410'
                                    ]                       
                ]           
            ]
                
        ]
    ]
];
$result = $connection->post('direct_messages/events/new', $data, true); // Note the true

echo json_encode($result);


?>
```

**Code 2:**

```
<?PHP
require_once 'twitteroauth.php';

define("CONSUMER_KEY", "Rh4USPExxxxxxxxHLIs7G");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "fUw7mPjxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxSHxynfkJGgz");
define("OAUTH_TOKEN", "13xxxxxxxxxxxxx3-DPAhGlvMQxxxxxxxxxxxxxxGhpcVmrrlgNN23");
define("OAUTH_SECRET", "b6xyCQxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxgPh3QdSEBxKj1fdc");


$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET);

$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
$image = 'walkswithme.png';
$status_message = 'Adjuntando Imagen a un Twt';
$status = $connection->upload('statuses/update_with_media', array('status' => null, 'media[]' => file_get_contents($image)));
echo json_encode($status);


?>
```

Thanks for all!!

Comment: You need to use `media/upload` instead - the Tweet `update_with_media` endpoint has been deprecated for many years. Check the media guide here (and take the `media_id_string` into the DM call) https://twitteroauth.com/

Comment: Thanks, I already updated my code. However I still have the question: how can I send a DM with an image without having to upload the image as a tweet.
Let me explain, currently I have to upload the image as a tweet to get the ID of the image that I am going to send by DM. Could you give me an example of how to send a DM with attached image, please

Comment: I do not have a PHP example of this as I don’t use PHP very often, but the steps are: use `media/upload` to create a new media object (set to shared); take the returned `media_id_string` from the response; Send JSON data to POST `direct_messages/events/new` and include an `attachment_type` of `media` and an `attachment.media.id` that matches the media object you uploaded.

Comment: Thanks Andy!

Finally, mi code:
$data = [
    'event' => [
        'type' => 'message_create',
        'message_create' => [
            'target' => [
                'recipient_id' => $userId
            ],
            'message_data' => [
               'attachment' => [
      'type' => 'media',
         'media' => [
          'id' => implode(',', [$media1->media_id_string]),
        'media_type' => 'image/jpeg',
        'media_category'=>'dm_image'
        ]
    ]   
            ]
    
        ]
    ]
];